# Why I'm getting this error when trying to establish a connection with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert values in the table but when I click on the SignUp button it gives me error

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file Database.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to
>   attach an auto-named database for file Database.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 22:  string con =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
>   Line 23:            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
>   Line 24:
>   conn.Open();  //error line
>    Line 25:         if (selectques.SelectedItem.Text ==
>   "Write your own question?")
>    Line 26:         {

My button event

```
protected void signup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);

   conn.Open();

   if (selectques.SelectedItem.Text == "Write your own question?")
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration values('" + username + "','" + passwrd + "','" + emailadd + "','" + alterquestion + "','" + securityanswer + "'", conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
   else
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration values('" + username + "','" + passwrd + "','" + emailadd + "','" + selectques + "','" + securityanswer + "'", conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
```

And my `web.config` connectionstring

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" 
         connectionString="server=.\sqlexpress; AttachdbFilename=Database.mdf; integrated security=true; user instance=true"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Some things to check: Is the Database.mdf file located in the App_Data directory of the website? Is SqlServerExpress installed on the target server?

Comment: @Joel Etherton Yes its installed on my PC and connected very well. But I'm getting this error for any DB with websites on local system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of your connection string is wrong:

```
AttachdbFilename=Database.mdf
```

`AttachdbFilename` needs a full path to the MDF file, not just its name.

Source:
[Connecting to SQL Server Express User Instances (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx)

Quote from the link:

> The AttachDbFileName connection string keyword is used to attach the primary database file (.mdf), which must include the full path name.

Comment: +1: I had forgotten that attribute requires an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
AttachdbFilename=Database.mdf
```

to this:

```
AttachdbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf
```